# Facebook [PHP] Video Post not Appear After API Call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have sent api call over Graph API on facebook . Video is sent successfully. Neither i can see video as incognito mode nor my friend can see the video. But i am able to see the video on publishing tools page . Just curious about that does anyone know any recent changes on Facebook side that i didn't follow ?

Or can anyone help. I couldn't share the code since i am using the default Facebook PHP SDK.

I am using share later or share on previous date. Both ended up with failure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your app is still in dev mode. You need to put it in live mode, before any content created through it will become visible to any users that don’t have a role in your app.

Comment: @04FS i have been using this app around 2 years and this is the first time i have encountered this kind of problem.

Comment: _“I couldn't share the code since i am using the default Facebook PHP SDK.”_ - that  provides the basic methods, but doesn’t perform any uploads on its own … so you must have some own coding around that.

Comment: @04FS Yes i have coding top of the facebook sdk but i haven't changed anything and around 2 days ago it stopped working.